# Need help in writing a simple progam

Tags: python

I am not a programmer. This is my first program.

I am trying to:

- copy a web page to a variable
- search the variable for a string

I got #1 to work but when i search for the string "June 5, 2017", I get the error listed below.

**Error Message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Family\Documents\Python Programs\webpagecopy2.py", line 8, in <module>
    if "June 5, 2017" in webPageCopy:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

**Here's the code:**

```
# webpagecopy2.py
import urllib.request
webpagestring = " "
url = 'https://www.nwbio.com/press-releases/'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
webPageCopy = response.read()
print(webPageCopy)
if "June 5, 2017" in webPageCopy: 
   print ('success')
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Because `"June 5, 2017"`  is a str object, and `webPageCopy` is a bytes-like object.

You need to  convert `webPageCopy` to str type.

```
if "June 5, 2017" in str(webPageCopy):
```

Or make "June 5, 2017" just be a byte-like object when defined as Wasi Ahmad mentioned.

```
if b"June 5, 2017" in webPageCopy:
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this.

```
if b"June 5, 2017" in webPageCopy: 
   print ('success')
```

In your example, all the data that you got from `response.read()` is bytes objects, not string. You can see what is the type of an object in python as follows.

```
print(type(webPageCopy)) # prints - <class 'bytes'>
```

So, adding a prefix (`b`) prefix before the target string solves your problem.

Other alternatives:

```
if bytes("June 5, 2017", 'utf8') in webPageCopy: 
    print ('success')
```

or,

```
if "June 5, 2017".encode('utf8') in webPageCopy: 
   print ('success')
```

Answer (score 0):

`webPageCopy` is a [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) object, not a string, so in order to use the `in` operator with it, you'd have to supply another `bytes` (or bytes-like) object. Luckily, this is quite easy in Python - just use the `b` prefix when you denote the literal:

```
if b"June 5, 2017" in webPageCopy: 
   print ('success')
```